# How to work with branch and link

Tags: hyperlink, arm, branch

This is the object dump file but I cannot understand why branch and link is always `0xebfffffe` in arm mode:

```
 7 00000000 <main>:
 8    0:   e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
 9    4:   e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
10    8:   e24dd008        sub     sp, sp, #8
11    c:   e3a0300a        mov     r3, #10
12   10:   e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
13   14:   e51b0008        ldr     r0, [fp, #-8]
14   18:   ebfffffe        bl      2c <fib>
15   1c:   e50b000c        str     r0, [fp, #-12]
16   20:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
17   24:   e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
18   28:   e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
19
20 0000002c <fib>:
21   2c:   e92d4810        push    {r4, fp, lr}
22   30:   e28db008        add     fp, sp, #8
23   34:   e24dd014        sub     sp, sp, #20
```

It is different from fib's address calculated with the reference manual's method.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be: [Relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing))

You probably used a compiled object (*.o) file - but the final address is calculated in the linker, and it will be put in place once the finished program has been linked. Before that a placeholder is used instead.

Comment: thanks for your answering, and can i ask another Q? how can i get the final address included binary file??

Comment: you do the math.   you would have to link or simulate the link if you are trying to use this object on your own.

Comment: create some simple examples and let the tool do it then from there you can understand the arm documentation (if you dont already which is where the answer to your question is).